# iterative dom tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal, children, parents

I'm iterating little bits of jQuery for other people to use.

However, to get this to work I'm hoping to traverse up and then down the dom tree. This is so that the effects stay within the wrapping div, rather than affect the whole page. (I'm assuming multiple iterations of the same 'wrappingdivclass' and its content)

```
<div class="wrappingdivclass" >
  <h4>series name</h4>
     <div class="hoverheaders">
         <p class="hoverheading"><!-- TEXT HERE (FOR INITIAL IMAGE) !-->image</p>
         <p class="hoverheading1"><!-- IMAGE TWO TEXT !-->image</p>
         <p class="hoverheading2"><!-- IMAGE THREE TEXT !-->image</p>
        <p class="hoverheading3"><!-- IMAGE FOUR TEXT !-->image</p>    
     </div>
     <div class="hovercontents">
          <p class="hovercontent">athing</p>
          <p class="hovercontent1">athing</p>
          <p class="hovercontent2">athing</p>
          <p class="hovercontent3">athing</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery (lives in an outside file)
these iterates for hoverheading1-3 and hovercontent1-3

example:

```
//does not work
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hovercontent").show();
  jQuery(".hoverheading").hover(function()
  {
    $(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").show()
    $(this).parent().children(".hovercontent").siblings().hide();
  });
});
//      $(".hovercontent2").siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

example 2:

```
//also does not work
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hovercontent1").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".hoverheading1").hover(function()
   {
    jQuery(this).closest(".hovercontent1").show();
    jQuery(this).closest(".hovercontent1").siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: I recommend adding the 'javascript' and 'jquery' tags to your question to increase the audience of folks who are likely to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be consistent.....either use the $ or use JQuery. You should avoid mixing them....
You might also benefit from using descendant selectors.

$(".wrappingdivclass > .hovercontents > .hovercontent2")

//Selects elements of class "hovercontent2" that have a parent element of "hovercontents", whose parent element is "wrappingdivclass"

$(".wrappingdivclass .hovercontent2")

//Selects elementss of class "hovercontent2" that are indirect descendants of "wrappingdivclass". Indirect means that it doesn't have to be direct child....it could be the grand-child, etc....

Comment: $ v. jQuery is easy enough to fix, but seems to have no effect on the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to call all three at once? or Are you commenting out the ones that didn't work?

Comment: I gave two examples that don't work, but show my sad attempt at DOM traversal.. the third 'works' but affects everything on the page rather than just whatever is within the wrappingdiv

Comment: $(".wrappingdivclass > .hovercontents > .hovercontent2")

Comment: that should only select the <p class="hovercontent2"> that are contained within <div class="hovercontents">, contained by "<div class="wrappingdivclass">

Comment: there are iterations of the entire thing on the same page.
so $(".wrappingdivclass > .hovercontents > .hovercontent2")
is on the page a few times...

that is the problem I wanted to solve by using traversal up/down rather than calling classes.

Comment: maybe you don't understand JQuery selectors? That selector applies to all elements that it matches, not simply the first match it finds.

Comment: yes, I edited to make it a better question..

per last comment: yes, that is why I'm trying to use (this).parent().children('.hovercontent")

Comment: try using parent child relationships and .find() instead of .closest()

Comment: like this?

jQuery(this).parent().find(".hovercontent1").show();
  jQuery(this).parent().find(".hovercontent1").siblings().hide();